# Bootstrap Card Image is not rendering

Tags: pug, bootstrap-5

Im using Pug template engine with bootstrap and I'm trying to load my `Model object` into a card like below,

```
- let models = response.data
    div(class='container-fluid my-5')
        div(class="row justify-content-center")
            each model in models
                div(class="col-sm-3")
                    div(class="card my-2 text-center")
                        img(src=model.image class="card-img-top py-1" style="height: 10rem; object-fit: contain;")
                        div(class="card-body")
                            h5 #{model.name}
                            h6 serieses : #{model.serieses.length}
                            form(action="/admin/getModels" method="get")
                                input(type="hidden" name="model_id" value=model._id)
                                button(type='submit' class='btn btn-primary') Details
```

Every thing is working but the image is never rendering? I even tried to hardcoding the image url but its also not working!

Any help, ideas will be much appreciated

Comment: Try unindenting the second line until the `div` is on the left margin, same indent level as the first line.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the indentation. The div block should not be part of the JS line

```
- let models = response.data
div(class='container-fluid my-5')
    div(class="row justify-content-center")
    ...
```